# Cannot install bob.measure python package

Tags: python, pip, python-bob

I have installed all the dependencies of bob.measure according to the graph presented in https://github.com/idiap/bob/wiki/Dependencies and https://github.com/idiap/bob/wiki/Installation:

However, I cannot install the package this is the traceback:

```
omar@ubuntuv2:~/bob.measure$ sudo python setup.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 50, in <module>
    boost_modules = boost_modules,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bob/blitz/extension.py", line 52, in __init__
    BobExtension.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 294, in __init__
    bob_includes, bob_libraries, bob_library_dirs, bob_macros = get_bob_libraries(self.bob_packages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 186, in get_bob_libraries
    pkg = importlib.import_module(package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bob/math/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    bob.extension.load_bob_library('bob.math', __file__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 237, in load_bob_library
    ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(full_libname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bob/math/libbob_math.so: undefined symbol: dsyevd_
```

All the bob.measure dependencies are up to date.
I have an Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libblitz0-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff5
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff-tools
sudo apt-get install giflib-dbg
```

Try installing using pip

```
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install bob.extension
$ pip install bob.blitz
$ pip install bob.core
$ pip install bob.io.base
$ pip install bob.io.image
```

Install bob.measure

Install following dependencies if not present

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
sudo apt-get  install libcppnetlib-dev
sudo apt-get  install python-netlib
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Use pip3

```
sudo pip3 install bob.measure
```

Comment: I have tried that without any success, every dependence is installed successfully except for Bob . measure

Comment: None,  only Bob. Measure

Comment: @user3025898 use pip3 install bob.measure. It works. If you have dependencies then install them using my answer

Comment: PIP 3 is for python3 I am using python 2

Comment: The error you are getting is from old netlib library. you should upgrade your python or can have both python2 and python3 together as well

Comment: apt-get install python3-pip

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Remove all bob packages, such as:

```
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install bob.extension
$ pip install bob.blitz
$ pip install bob.core
$ pip install bob.io.base
$ pip install bob.io.image
```

Do not remove installed dependencies.

then re-install bob with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties #to install "add-apt-repository"
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:biometrics/bob #only the first time
$ sudo apt-get update #repeat this every time you need to update
$ sudo apt-get install bob
```

from: https://github.com/idiap/bob/wiki/Binary-Installation